# What is the wattage formula for a printed resistor?

Tags: power, pcb, resistors

what is the formula to find power rating or power difference for printed resistor which is dependent on Length L,width W,thickness t &   Resistivity Rs   in hybrid micro design. 
,if suppose my requirement is 10ohm Resistivity [Ω/](i require length and width of the resistor is L=3.008 and W=1.072) from heraeus 8911 which is having Short term overload voltage [V/mm]=9, Standard working voltage [V/mm]=3.6,Maximum rated power dissipation [mW/mm2]=1300,so from this whats the power rating of my resistor which is having length =3.008mm and w=1.072mm– and which is printed on the Al2Og( Aluminum ceramic substrate) substrate having 99% of alumina
after printing the resistor is dried at 150 degree centegrade for 1hour and at 850 degree centigrade for 10minutes

Comment: I know the formula for printer resistor which is R=Rs*L/W*t, I want to know the wattage  of printed resistor which is  dependent on L,W & t.Because once printed resistor gets trimmed normally 50% wattage reduction happens.

Comment: The watt rating of a resistor depends on how hot the resistor is allowed to get, and how fast it can dissipate heat to its surroundings. That is, you need to know the thermal properties of the materials you are using.

Comment: It's better to edit any additional information into the question rather than as comments to make the question clearer. A long string of comments makes things harder for those reading the question to follow.

Comment: Plus, comments are intended to be temporary and will go away eventually.  Your resistors thermal ability will be dependant upon the substrate so please include details of that too.

Comment: thanks u @rawbrawg..will try to update the question with all details..since m new to this site i donno how to present it..even m a fresh engineer.....

Comment: @kshama Well, to start with, SMS-speak, such as "*m a fresh engineer*" is pretty much unwelcome here. Writing "*I am a ...*" just makes your writing come across as more professional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already know the aspect ratio (3.008/1.072 = 2.806) for your resistor, and you know the power dissipation that the material is capable of (1300 mW/mm<sup>2</sup>).

Once you know the peak power dissipation you require, it's simply a matter of scaling your resistor so that it covers the required area.

For example, suppose that you need a 10W resistor. The area required will be 10/1.3 = 7.69 mm<sup>2</sup>. The length of your resistor will be the square root of the area times the aspect ratio:

$$L = \sqrt{AR}$$

$$L = \sqrt{7.69 mm^2 \cdot 2.806} = 4.646 mm$$

$$W = L/R = 1.656 mm$$

Note that if the resistance will be trimmed, you will lose some of the power-dissipating area, so scale the as-printed resistor to have enough margin to allow for this.

Comment: Answer is not clear.m not able to understand.To know aspect ratio i need to know the length and width and also from this i am not getting what is the wattage of my resistor which is having length 3.008 and width-1.072

Comment: and what ever the resistor length and width i provided having different wattage and how can you use that resistor aspect ratio to find another resistor which having wattage 10W??

Comment: Look again at the formula for the resistance value. As long as Rs and t are constant, the resistance only depends on L/W. Both L and W have units of length, so the units cancel, leaving just what I'm calling the "aspect ratio". A resistor that's 3.008 x 1.072 mm has a resistance of 28.06 ohms, and has an area of 3.225 mm^2, giving a power disspation of 4.2 W. A resistor that's 3.008 x 1.072 cm *also* has a resistance of 28.06 ohms, but has an area of 322.5 mm^2, giving a power disspation of 420 W. The point is that you can scale the resistor to the size you need to get the power you need.

Comment: Thank you @Dave for beautiful explanation,now my doubt is suppose i know the resistor value which is 28ohm from that i need to design a resistor even i know the paste 8911 Rs is 10ohm,power dissipation=250mW, how can i find the length and width of the resistor??

Comment: Seriously? What did you not understand about my original answer? Area = 250 mW/1300 mW = 0.1923 mm^2. Length = \$\sqrt{0.1923*2.806}\$ = 0.735 mm. Width = 0.735/2.806 = 0.262 mm.

Comment: Now i understood everything,actually here in my office we have 1 software to find the length & width of the resistor,if we just input resistivity,resistance, wattage and % of design we gets length and width of the resistor, but no where that software is demanding the thermal property of the material using,even with that software if we input length and width  we can get resistance wattage vice verse. My doubt is what formula they have used to find the length and width without considering the thermal property of the resistor??? how it is right?? @dave

Comment: and here my doubt is how can you take 2.806 aspect ratio for this ??? because initially while designing we wont be knowing no what aspect ratio we should be taken?? is it possible to consider any aspect ratio for any resistance??  In my second question i just gave inputs are r=28E, watatge-250mW, Rs=10E, i dint give length and width no to find aspect ratio,but in this you can tell from previous question u got aspect ratio but suppose my resistor value is 14.2E,then you cant take this 2.806 aspect ratio right to find length and width??in this situation how can you find length and width? @Dave